# Unslider doesn't show navigation dots on the slider image

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexslider

Please help find out the issue with the navigation dots not appearing on the slides. The option to get the dots has been set to true as seen in the code below. This is from jQuery document on unslider found at https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Clean-Flexible-jQuery-Content-Slider-Plugin-unslider/

```
<!-- The HTML -->
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>

<head>
  <title>Unslider example</title>

  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/unslider/2.0.3/css/unslider.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/unslider-min.js"></script>

  <!-- JavaScript -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('.pwp-slider').unslider({
            autoplay:true,
            speed: 500,               //  The speed to animate each slide (in milliseconds)
            delay: 3000,              //  The delay between slide animations (in milliseconds)
            complete: function() {},  //  A function that gets called after every slide animation
            keys: true,               //  Enable keyboard (left, right) arrow shortcuts
            dots: true,               //  Display dot navigation
            fluid: false              //  Support responsive design. May break non-responsive designs
        });
    });
  </script>

  <!-- CSS -->
  <style type="text/css">
    .pwp-slider {
      position: relative;
      overflow: auto;
    }
    
    .pwp-slider ul li {
      list-style-type: none;
    }
    
    .pwp-slider ul li {
      float: left;
    }
    
    .unslider-nav {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<!-- Body of HTML document -->

<body>
  <div class="pwp-slider">
    <ul>
      <li><img src="http://www.unsplash.it/2000/501" alt="" /></li>
      <li><img src="http://www.unsplash.it/2000/502" alt="" /></li>
      <li><img src="http://www.unsplash.it/2000/503" alt="" /></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you make this runnable ?

Comment: I am not sure how to do it except on my wamp.

Comment: you are missing css file . check this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wLfuy46h/)

Comment: Wonderful, it works now. I would accept it if you could answer with your response.

Comment: Hi, no it was just a typo .But , you can answer your own question :)

Comment: Appreciate your gentleness. I find the slides not changing from one to the other unless next is clicked. Not sure why

Comment: Just add `autoplay:true` i.e : `$('.banner').unslider({autoplay: true});` and follow [this](https://frontendscript.com/unslider-simplest-carousel-slider-jquery/) page(Events sections) you will find more options.

Comment: That does it:) thanks

Comment: Hi Swati, can you please have a look at this when you are free? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67311801/how-to-set-the-height-of-two-columns-to-the-highest-of-them-with-jquery?noredirect=1#comment118978035_67311801