# How to set the height of both the columns to the highest of them with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

A sheetdb plugin pulls data from a shared googlesheet to display them on a WordPress site. The page displays nothing else but this dynamic contents from the googlesheet. It is a simple page. Below is custom field content from WordPress page editor. This is what prints data on the page via template(Code added at the end of this post)

```
[sheetdb url="https://sheetdb.io/api/v1/ymk583vab4dwh" search="Approval=1&amp;Display=1"]
<div class="story-entry">
  <div class="content"> {{Story}} </div>
  <div class="contestent-name">-{{First Name}} {{Initial}}</div>
</div>
[/sheetdb]
```

CSS for the div displaying columns on the page.

```
.story-entry {
  margin: 15px 10px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  width: calc(50% - 22px);
  float: left;
}

<?php $story = get_field('story'); ?>

<div class="contest-story">
  <div class="wrap-x">
    <div class="inside">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="contest-story-text col col-xs-12"><?php echo do_shortcode($story); ?></div>  
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem with the columns is them having the same height resulting in unnecessary wastage of the extra space. I got the logic to dynamically find out the max height of the two columns and set both them to the max height.

With the following jQuery code I am trying to use to set the height to both the columns.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var maxHeight = 0;
    var entryNumber = 1;
    var prevEntrySelector = null;
    $(".story-entry").each(function(){
    alert('Hello');
       if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) { maxHeight = $(this).height(); }
       if ((entryNumber % 2) == 0) {
      // Even entry.
      // Set height of previous entry and this entry to maxHeight.
      $(this).height(maxHeight);
      prevEntrySelector.height(maxHeight);
      // this - this selector - this story entry
      maxHeight = 0;
       }
       prevEntrySelector = $(this);
       entryNumber ++;
    });

    $(".entry-selector").height(maxHeight);
});
```

This code doesn't work on [this](https://dev-packed-with-purpose.pantheonsite.io/mothers-day-2021-entries/) page. Below is the reference page.

https://knackshops.com/pages/spread-joy-message

What I did so far is as seen below with unnecessary space after the content

[image]

This is the [page](https://dev-packed-with-purpose.pantheonsite.io/mothers-day-2021-entries/) that I want to make look like [this](https://packedwithpurpose.gifts/mothers-day-2021-entries/) with jQuery.

The full template code for this page:

```
<?php 
$hero = get_field('hero');
$hero_h1 = $hero['hero_-_h1'];
$hero_h2 = $hero['hero_-_h2'];
$background = $hero['hero_-_background_options'];
$image = $background['background_-_image'];

$link_text = get_field('link_text');
$link_to_contest = get_field('link_to_contest');

$story = get_field('story');
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="default-flex-hero relative">
  <div class="inside">
    <div class="row mb0 pt pb">
    <?php if($image): ?>
      <div class="col col-xs-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2 mb0">
          <picture>
            <source media="(max-width: 480px)" srcset="<?php echo($image['sizes']['small']); ?>">
            <source media="(max-width: 1024px)" srcset="<?php echo($image['sizes']['medium']); ?>">
            <source media="(max-width: 1280px)" srcset="<?php echo($image['sizes']['large']); ?>">
            <source srcset="<?php echo($image['sizes']['xlarge']); ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo($image['sizes']['xlarge']); ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
          </picture>
        </div>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <div class="hero-col col col-xs-12 col-md-10 col-lg-10 mb0">
              <h1 class="mb0 color-tan-dark">
                <?php if( $hero_h1 ): echo $hero_h1; endif; ?>
              </h1>
              <?php if( $hero_h2 ): ?>
              <h2 class="mb0 mt2 alt-heading h4">
                <?php echo $hero_h2; ?>
              </h2>
              <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="contest-link">
  <div class="wrap-x">
    <div class="inside">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="contest-link-text col col-xs-12">
        SHARE YOUR OWN STORY <a href="<?php echo $link_to_contest; ?>">HERE</a>
        </div>  
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

**<div class="contest-story">
  <div class="wrap-x">
    <div class="inside">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="contest-story-text col col-xs-12"><?php echo do_shortcode($story); ?></div>  
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>**

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: I don't see the html related to your jquery. where is `story-entry`

Comment: It is at the very top of the post..

Comment: You jquery says `$(".story-entry")` but at the top it says `contest-entry-row`. I cant find any element with the class `story-entry` only a css with that class `story-entry`

Comment: Apologies. Edited the post now with the latest code. I got three environments and copied the code from the one that has old code.

Comment: This is the page where I am trying to dynamically set the highest height of the columns to both the columns. https://dev-packed-with-purpose.pantheonsite.io/mothers-day-2021-entries/

Comment: Can't use ```flexbox``` for this instead of ```float```?

Comment: @prettyInPink, not sure. I am fine with flexbox if it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do with css
just add these line

```
.contest-story-text > div{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
}

.story-entry {
    height: auto !important;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .story-entry {
            width: calc(100% - 22px) !important
    }
}
```

Comment: Amazing, you just not only fixed the primary issue, but also addressed the mobile responsiveness too. Thanks a lot man. I am also interested in how to use jQuery to accomplish this. Could you please look into it?

Comment: Although I found jQuery based solution, I find yours elegant solution.

Comment: Sumit, I hope your day is beautiful. I'm trying to set the height of all three texts above the buttons to the maximum of them so that all buttons(shop now, Order Here, connect with an expert) appear in a single line.

https://dev-packed-with-purpose.pantheonsite.io/how-to-order-new/

Can this be achieved only with CSS? Or do I need to use jQuery.

Comment: Sumit, please help me find the similar solution to the problem posted here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73446618/css-equivalent-of-a-jquery-solution-to-set-max-height-to-all-elements?noredirect=1#comment129703731_73446618

Answer (score 0):

I finally accomplished it with jQuery and an eventhandler for the plugin sheetdb.

```
window.addEventListener("sheetdb-downloaded", function() {
  var maxHeight = 0;
    var entryNumber = 1;
    var prevEntrySelector = null;
    $(".story-entry").each(function(index) {
    if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) { maxHeight = $(this).height(); }
    if ((entryNumber % 2) == 0) {
      // Even entry.
      // Set height of previous entry and this entry to maxHeight.
      $(this).height(maxHeight);
      prevEntrySelector.height(maxHeight);
      // this - this selector - this story entry
      console.log( "Height: " + maxHeight );
      maxHeight = 0;
    }
    prevEntrySelector = $(this);
    entryNumber ++;
    return true;
    });
    $(".entry-selector").height(maxHeight);
});
```