# CSS equivalent of a jQuery solution to set max height to all elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

With the jQuery code below, I could reset the height of 3 elements to the max of them. I would like to replace it with an CSS-based solution.

```
  // Set max height.
  var maxHeight = 0;
  var prevEntrySelector = null;
  $(".send-submit-look-col .icon-description").each(function(index) {
    if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) { 
      maxHeight = $(this).height(); 
    }
    // Set height of previous entry and this entry to maxHeight.
    $(this).height(maxHeight);
    if (prevEntrySelector != null) {
      prevEntrySelector.height(maxHeight);
    }
    // this - this selector - this story entry
    console.log( "Height: " + maxHeight );
    prevEntrySelector = $(this);
    return true;
  });
```

The image below shows the section.

[image]

Could you please help find the CSS solution? Here is the [page](https://dev-packed-with-purpose.pantheonsite.io/how-to-order-new/)

Comment: where is the HTML?

Comment: You could utilise Flexbox to do this?

Comment: Naren, please see the link to the page in the updated post. Thanks for looking

Comment: @AndyHolmes, Yes, I am aware that it can be used, but not sure how to use it to solve this. Could you please help? I added the link to the page in the updated post.

Comment: @PramodGangadar https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ - this guide will show you exactly what you need to know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your website this might fix your issue, `flex-grow: 1` will make the div fill the maximum space!

```
.send-submit-look-row .send-submit-look-col {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.send-submit-look-row .send-submit-look-col .icon-description {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```